# Save Excel OLE Object to disk via MATLAB

Tags: excel, vba, matlab

I have a spreadsheet with two jpeg files embedded in it. I would like to extract these and write them to a specific directory. I can do this in VBA as:

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Photo Object 1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    DestinationFolder = "C:..."
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(CVar(DestinationFolder)).self.InvokeVerb "Paste"


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range("Photo Object 2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(CVar(DestinationFolder)).self.InvokeVerb "Paste"
End Sub
```

I'd like to do the same through MATLAB. So far what I've got the following:.

```
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
fullFileName = 'C:\....xls';
invoke(Excel.Workbooks, 'Open', fullFileName);
Workbook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook;
Worksheets = Workbook.sheets;
objects=Worksheets.Item(1).OLEObjects;
image1=Item(objects,1); % This is photo object 1
image2=Item(objects,2); % This is photo object 2
Copy(image1)
objShell = actxserver('Shell.Application');
DestinationFolder = 'C:\';
objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DestinationFolder);
objFolderItem = objFolder.Self;
```

This gives the error that Self is not recognized. I can't work out how to paste the  to my preferred directory. The copied image exists in the system clipboard.